# adding value limitations on list comprehension

Tags: python, colors, rgb, list-comprehension

I am trying to find a clean way of grabbing the difference between the values of two int tuples. The tuples themselves have limitations though as they represent RGB colors. This is what I have so far:

```
tupleone = (255, 0, 255)  # Magenta
tupletwo = (255, 0, 0)  # Red
tuple([tupleone[x] - tupletwo[x] for x in range(3)])  # makes Blue
```

The problem I have here is bounds checking since each color value must be 0-255. What I'm going for is if a larger number is subtracted from a smaller, to return 0 for that given index. I have been using this to test a single index:

```
value = -10
max(0, min(color, 255))  # value = 0
```

Is this something that I can cleanly do with list comprehensions? Or was there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just combine what you've got there:

```
tuple(max(0, min(tupleone[x] - tupletwo[x], 255)) for x in range(3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way

```
tuple(sorted((0, 255, tupleone[x] - tupletwo[x]))[1] for x in range(3))
```

but probably you should just use a function

```
def clamp_0_255(x):
    return max(0, min(x, 255))

tuple(clamp_0_255(tupleone[x] - tupletwo[x]) for x in range(3))
```

Aside: You don't need to use a list comprehension. `tuple()` works fine with a generator expression

Comment: Nice use of `sorted()` there.